# global name error in class python program

Tags: python

Define a class Circle, whose objects are initialized with radius as it's attribute.

Ensure that the object creation raises RadiusInputError, a user defined exception, when the input radius is not a number.

For e.g : Circle('hello') -> RadiusInputError : 'hello' is not a number

Below code i have written and throwing error:

class circle:

```
def __init__(self,r):
    self.r=r

    try:
        if  isinstance(r,str):
            raise RadiusInputError("error ")
        else:
            print(r)
    except RadiusInputError as error:
        print(error)

circle("Hello")
```

Error seeing as: except RadiusInputError as error:

```
NameError: global name 'RadiusInputError' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just use an exception name that you have not created. Like everything in Python, an exception is an object, you have to define it before using it.

Also, your current code would raise the exception, but then catch it. You want the exception to bubble up to the user.

```
import numbers

class RadiusInputError(Exception):
    pass

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        if not isinstance(radius, numbers.Number):
            raise RadiusInputError(f'{repr(radius)} is not a number')

        self.radius = radius

Circle('hello') # __main__.RadiusInputError: 'hello' is not a number
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class RadiusInputError(Exception):
    pass
class circle:
    def __init__(self,r):
        self.r=r
        try:
            if  isinstance(r,str):
                raise RadiusInputError("error ")
            else:
                print(r)

        except RadiusInputError as error:
            print(r+"is not a number")

circle("Hello")
```